# Rails remember form checkbox value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

```
 <% User.tag_counts_on(:tags).each do |tag| %>
    <%= f.check_box(:tag_list, { :multiple => true }, tag, nil ) %>
    <li class="tag-name"><%= tag.name %></li>
 <% end %>
```

The code above doesn't remember the selected value when the validation fails on sign up. Also on the edit page it doesn't remember what my selected tags are. Any suggestions?

Comment: The tags are stored in another model with a many_to_many relationship? You are probably looking for `f.association`. Have a look at the documentation. You do not need to iterate trough each tag, Rails is smart enough to sort that out for itself. (btw f.association is specific for simple_form I realized)

Comment: With normal form helper, there's collection_select, but it doesn't do checkboxes I suppose: `<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>`.

Comment: Can you show us the containing form creation (the `form_for` line)?

Comment: @bo-oz `f.select :tag_list, options_for_select(User.tag_counts_on(:tags)), {}, {:multiple => true, :class => "tags-select" }` This code seems to remember the selected value even after other validation fails. However, I wanted it to be a checkbox

Comment: @DavidAvikasis It's a devise form_for `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`

Comment: This is pretty simple with simple_form, maybe consider using that, it's a pretty common gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form